# Get key after inserting into array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for something like this:

```
$a = array();

$var1 = 'var1';
$var2 = 'var2';

$i = array_push($a, $var1);
$j = array_push($a, $var2);

echo $i;
echo $j;
```

The expected output would be:

```
0
1
```

I want to know the index of the object I just inserted, to be able to find it quickly afterwards. I think array_push gives me the size of the resulting array, not the index for the recently inserted element

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?  If you want the size, just use `-1`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I dont want the size! I want the index where the element was inserted. So i can do `$a[$i]` and get `var1` .. I also need it to  work after removing elements as well. Every time I insert an element, I want to know where it is so I can remove it later if I need

Comment: If `array_push()` gives you the index, then `array_push() - 1` will give you the index.

Comment: You must not use numeric keys in php 'arrays' expecting them to reference the same item, if you manipulate the array, as the keys can change when the values are 're-arranged'. String keys tend to stay as 'keys' of the associated item.

Answer (score 1):

`array_push` `return` new number of elements in the array, so decrement the return value by 1

Try this:

```
$a = array();

$var1 = 'var1';
$var2 = 'var2';

$i = array_push($a, $var1) - 1;
$j = array_push($a, $var2) - 1;

echo $i;
echo $j;
```

Comment: yeah but what happens if `unset($a[$i])` and then insert a new element? it wont work then

Comment: @Alex - Correct.  `array_push()` returns the size after the function returns.  What you do from there is up to you, but you can always call `count()` later to find the new size.  If you array has holes, consider using `array_keys()` instead.

Comment: If you are calling `unset($a[$i])` before `$j = array_push($a, $var2) - 1;` then this approach will not work, you have to use associative array for that

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_push_array(&$array, $value){
  $array[] = $value;
  end($array);
  return key($array);
}

$a = ['h','e','l','l'];
echo my_push_array($a, 'o'); //returns 4
```